# Ordenamiento de fechas por arreglos en Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

tengo un arreglo de la siguiente manera 
[{
nombre:"---",
fecha: "05-06-2019"
},
{
nombre:"---",
fecha: "08-06-2019"
},
{
nombre:"---",
fecha: "10-01-2019"
}
]
Quisiera ordernar el arreglo de forma de fecha mas cercana hasta la mas lejana, como podria hacerlo ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza la función `sort` para arreglos, esta realiza el ordenamiento sobre la misma instancia del arreglo y le puedes pasar una función como parámetro que le indica de que manera realizar la comparación de elementos.

```js
var lista = [{ nombre:"tercero", fecha: "03-01-2019" }, { nombre:"segundo", fecha: "02-01-2019" }, { nombre:"primero", fecha: "01-01-2019" } ];

console.log(lista);

lista.sort((a, b) => {
  // si las fechas tienen formato día-mes-año 
  // entonces hay que manipular un poco para crear el objeto Date correctamente
  var partes = a.fecha.split('-'); 
  var fa = new Date(partes[2], partes[1], partes[0]);
  partes = b.fecha.split('-');
  var fb = new Date(partes[2], partes[1], partes[0]);
  
  return fa - fb;
});

console.log(lista);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias , la verdad no conocía a fondo lo que es el .sort